# How to make reviews show up

Tags: magento, magento2

Magento newbie here. Currently I inserted a few thousand reviews for a magento test product which ran succefully. Only problem now is that when I go to Catalog > Products > Product Reviews, it will find all the reviews but it wont display them. Instead I get "No Records Found"

what can cause such error?

[What my current product reviews show.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Affx.png)

Comment: Can you show us some examples of what you inserted in the database? And also did you make any changes to the code of admin reviews grid ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?